# php echo link with variable in the url

Tags: php, echo

```
a href=templateIndex.php?'.$row["title"].'>'.$row["title"].'/a>
```

code goes something like this, although it seems to work it only actually puts part of the variable in the url on redirect, so title is the title of a game, but say the game was Farming Simulator, it only puts Farming in the url. any suggestions?

Comment: try to use `urlencode($row["title"])`

Comment: a href=templateIndex.php?'.urlencode($row["title"]).'>'.urlencode($row["title"]).'/a>                                     like this then?

Comment: first one is enough, but code looks to have other issues

Comment: thanks seems to work, if i knew how to mark it as the solution or the question as solved i would

Answer (score 0):

To append parameter string with spaces to URL you need to use `urlencode`:

```
urlencode($row["title"])
```

this function replaces spaces with '+' signs